# Handling K-means with large dataset 6gb with scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using scikit-learn. I want to cluster a 6gb dataset of documents and find clusters of documents.

I only have about 4Gb ram though. Is there a way to get k-means to handle large datasets in scikit-learn?

Thank you, Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`MiniBatchKMeans`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html) together with [`HashingVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#vectorizing-a-large-text-corpus-with-the-hashing-trick); that way, you can learn a cluster model in a single pass over the data, assigning cluster labels as you go or in a second pass. There's an [example script](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html) that demonstrates MBKM.

Comment: I've heard of it but it doesn't allow n_jobs which would be useful

Comment: @Highschooler: at such scales, minibatch k-means should be orders of magnitude faster. Also, you can do your own parallel processing using joblib.

Comment: Thank you. I'm also aware that MiniBatchKmeans will also lead to inaccurate results. How inaccurate do you think they would be?

Comment: @Highschooler: that depends on your data and the way you measure accuracy. I've had great success with MBKM on some problems, but I never compared to vanilla KM because it just wasn't feasible to run that on large datasets.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_clustering.html this link doesn't work anymore, can you please post alternative example script??

Answer (score 1):

Clustering is not in itself that well-defined a problem (a 'good' clustering result depends on your application) and k-means algorithm only gives locally optimal solutions based on random initialization criteria. Therefore I doubt that the results you would get from clustering a random 2GB subsample of the dataset would be qualitatively different from the results you would get clustering over the entire 6GB. I would certainly try clustering on the reduced dataset as a first port of call. Next options are to subsample more intelligently, or do multiple training runs with different subsets and do some kind of selection/ averaging across multiple runs.